# How to start a MongoDB replicaset with an existing instance with data?

Tags: database, mongodb, replication, database-replication, replicaset

I have an existing mongodb instance with data in it. I want to create a replicaset with the existing instance, so the rest of the set can sync from it.

The way I tried to do it in testing is initiating the replicaset and setting the existing instance as the primary in config, hoping that the secondaries will sync from it, but when the replicaset is created, all the data in the existing instance is gone.

I noticed at the moment of creating the replicaset, all the members start as a secondary, and then one becomes a primary, so I think this may be why my data is being deleted. Is there another way I can start a replicaset with data?

Comment: Check out the docs: [Convert a Standalone to a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/)

Comment: @Joe I did follow the docs. It works for a new instance with no data. With data, it just gets deleted when the replicaset is initiated, unless I did something wrong.

Comment: The step in the docs that saves the data is to run `rs.initiate()` with no arguments on the node that has the data.  That makes it primary by default.  Then when you add additional nodes with `rs.add`, they replicate the data.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial provided by @Joe is correct, however it is not very smart.

It works fine when you start your MongoDB from command line. But it should be noted, that you have to start your MongoDB **always** like

```
mongod --replSet rs0 ...
```

not just once while converting.

If you start MongoDB as service, then you also need to modify your config file (typically `mongod.conf`) in order to make replicaset persistent!